# Ant: Exclude Packageset Sub-Directory of Same Name as Another Packageset

Tags: java, ant, javadoc

I am trying to run a `javadoc` task in Apache Ant that documents packages from two separate directories: `src` & `tests`. I want to document everything under `src` & only the `utilities` sub-directory under `tests`. The problem is that both directories contain a sub-directory named `games`. By including the `games` directory from `src` it also forces the `games` directory to be included from `tests`.

Neither of the following work:

```
<target name="docs">
  <javadoc
      defaultexcludes="yes"
      destdir="docs/"
      author="true"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      version="true"
      use="true"
      failonerror="yes"
      additionalparam="-Xdoclint:-html">
    <packageset dir="src/"/>
    <packageset dir="tests/" includes="utilities/"/>
  </javadoc>
</target>
```

```
<target name="docs">
  <javadoc packagenames="games.*"
      defaultexcludes="yes"
      destdir="docs/"
      author="true"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      version="true"
      use="true"
      failonerror="yes"
      additionalparam="-Xdoclint:-html">
    <sourcepath path="src/"/>
    <packageset dir="tests/" includes="utilities/"/>
  </javadoc>
</target>
```

I have also tried the following, but `tests/games` is always forced to be included if `src/games` is.

```
  <javadoc packagenames="games.*"
...
    <sourcepath path="src/"/>
    <packageset dir="tests/" includes="utilities/" excludes="games/"/>
```

```
  <javadoc packagenames="games.*,utilities.*"
...
    <sourcepath path="src/"/>
    <sourcepath>
      <dirset dir="tests/" excludes="games/"/>
    </sourcepath>
```

```
  <javadoc packagenames="games.*"
...
    <sourcepath path="src/"/>
    <packageset dir="tests/">
      <patternset includes="utilities/"/>
    </packageset>
```

If I use a `sourcepath` for `src` & don't include "games.*" in `packagenames`, then the `tests/games` directory is omitted. But then I don't get any documentation for `src/games`.

```
  <javadoc packagenames="foobar"
...
    <sourcepath path="src/"/>
    <packageset dir="tests/" includes="utilities/"/>
```

I also tried using a nested `fileset`, but then there is a messages that all the files under the `tests` directory are skipped because the task wants a list of directories as input: `Skipping <filename>.java since it is no directory`

```
    <sourcepath>
      <fileset dir="tests/">
        <exclude name="games/**/*.java"/>
      </fileset>
    </sourcepath>
```

Is there any way around this so I can get documentation for both `src/games` & `tests/utilities` without `tests/games`? I have found many answers on excluding package directories. But nothing about when two package directories share the same name.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html states that:

> The *packagenames*, *excludepackagenames* and *defaultexcludes* attributes of the task have no effect on the nested `<packageset>` elements.

But this doesn't seem to be the case if another `packageset` or `sourcepath` is using the package name.

Java & Ant info:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)

$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.12 compiled on January 17 1970
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrect in thinking the task required a list of directories as input. By using the `sourcepath` & `packageset` tags it was looking for directories/packages. The answer was to use `fileset` instead.

```
  <javadoc
...
    <fileset dir="src/" includes="**/*.java"/>
    <fileset dir="tests/" includes="**/*.java" excludes="games/**"/>
```

This in turn required that I also add the `src` & `tests` directories to the classpath.

```
    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="src/"/>
      <pathelement path="tests/"/>
    </classpath>
```